# Merge 32bit and 64bit installer into one installer using NSIS

Tags: installation, 32bit-64bit, nsis

I have created a simple installer using NSIS. I want that the installer should detect the OS that a client is using.If a client is using a 32-bit OS then all the files should be copied to  Program Files(32 bit) folder or else if he/she is using a 64-bit OS, all the files should be copied to 64-bit.Can anyone help me how to figure this out..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as above (don't forget to include [LogicLib.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LogicLib) *and* x64.nsh)

```
Function .onInit

    ${If} ${RunningX64}
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\myProduct"
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\myProduct" ; $PROGRAMFILES32 also works
    ${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

Optionally, you can also set the registry view (see [SetRegView](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/SetRegView.md))

Comment: Thanks for replying.In which section should I add the above code?

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its working!! :-)

Stack Overflow always helps me with any type of programming issue..

Comment: I'd put it inside an .onInit function, will update the example above

Comment: I added a seperate section to include the code and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following code will do the task.

```
!include "x64.nsh"
.
.
.
.
var copyDir

section ""

${If} ${RunningX64}
strcpy $copyDir "C:\\Program Files(x64)\\Foo"

${else}
strcpy $copyDir "C:\\Program Files\\Foo"
sectionend
```

Although if its just about detecting the Program Files directory, I think `$ProgramFiles` will automatically detect the default Program Files directory according to the OS bit.